# VSC R debug console not reacting to input from user

Tags: r, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am debugging an R script in VSC. This script logs to Google API, so it prompts the user to select a pre-authorized account from a menu:

```
1: email1@email1.com
2: email2@email2.com
```

The problem is that after entering the menu option (`1`, in my case) and entering `Enter` in the `DEBUG CONSOLE`, the script doesn't continue even when the input is accepted and displayed in the console.

You can see an image of the DEBUG CONSOLE here:
[image]

As you can see, nothing happens after entering a menu option (when I debug this code in PyCharm, the script does continue after entering `1`)

Comment: My sense would be to ask which debugger are you using? The native debugger or an extension to Vsc? My recommendation would be to install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RDebugger.r-debugger&ssr=false#overview and see if that addresses your problem.

Comment: @Technophobe01 That extension is already installed, but the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***VSCode-R-Debugger*** starts and controls R programs by sending input to stdin of the ***child*** process. To take input in debug mode you have to enter the data in the debug console and prefix it with ***###stdin***. The feature is described via the following [Github](https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/pull/46) request and marked as resolved. I was able to use the following example code to confirm the solution is current and works as described:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

typeline <- function(msg = "Enter text: ") {
  if (interactive()) {
    txt <- readline(msg)
  } else {
    cat(msg)
    
    txt <- readLines("stdin", n = 1)
    
  }
  return(txt)
}

txt = typeline("your first message: ")
print(txt)
txt2 = typeline("your second message: ")
print(txt2)
```

If we set a breakpoint on lines 5 or 9, we can then receive stdin input by typing ***###stdin 5*** in the debug console. See the image below.

I am hoping this points you in the right direction. I was able to reproduce the behavior you describe and address the problem using the guidance in the feature request below:

Take care and stay safe.

#### References:

https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/pull/46

[image: Debug COnsole Image]

### Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
List of 13
_names: chr [1:13] "R.version" "platform" "locale" "running" "RNGkind" "basePkgs" ...
_class:"sessionInfo"
__unclass():List of 13
R.version:List of 14
platform:"x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0 (64-bit)"
locale:"en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
running:"macOS Monterey 12.1"
RNGkind: chr [1:3] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion" "Rejection"
basePkgs: chr [1:7] "stats" "graphics" "grDevices" "utils" "datasets" "methods" ...
otherPkgs:List of 1
loadedOnly:List of 6
matprod:"default"
BLAS:"/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.19/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.19.dylib"
LAPACK:"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib"
system.codepage:"NULL"
codepage:"NULL"
```